# How do I restore a default report template?

Tags: civireport

Using WP and current CiviCRM.
We changed a default Report Template.  Is there a way to restore a default report template?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know a way through the UI, but I think you could do it through SQL.

The default reports appear to be defined in `xml/templates/civicrm_navigation.tpl`, which in turn gets copied into `sql/civicrm_data.mysql`.

You might make a new instance with the default settings by copying the definition:

1. Open `sql/civircm_data.mysql` and search for `civicrm_report_instance`. Find the `INSERT` statement which corresponds to your report.
2. Copy the `INSERT` statement into a text editor.
3. Change `@domainID` to `1` (unless you have a special/multidomain system; then adjust accordingly).
4. Open your MySQL tool (e.g. `mysql` cli or `phpmyadmin`) with an appropriate user+database.
5. Paste and execute the `INSERT` statement.

If you want to reset the existing report and know a bit of SQL, then you can massage the `INSERT` and produce an `UPDATE` for the existing report.